# incident ticket priority classification in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am new to R and machine learning. Here I tried to build a random forest classification model to predict the priority of a incident ticket from its description. The below steps I followed.

1) Input <- description using CSV file

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(caTools)
library(randomForest)
incidents = read.csv("incident.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> str(incidents) 'data.frame':  4265 obs. of  7 variables:  $ number                : chr  "INC0031193" "INC0037867" "INC0159979" "INC0031446" ...  $
> u_detailed_description: chr  "Close & Ignore new Ticket New-Production
> SNOW Auto Routing test for XYZ SNOW ticketing in uat"  "" "" ""...  $
> priority              : chr  "3 - Moderate" "2 - High" "4 - Low" "3 -
> Moderate" ...  $ state                 : chr  "Canceled" "Canceled"
> "Canceled" "Canceled" ...  $ category              : chr  "Server"
> "Tools" "Server" "Server" ...  $ assignment_group      : chr 
> "Windows" "Tools" "SNOC Support" "Windows" ...
```

2) Data cleaning, creating DocumenTermMatrix and convert to DataFrame.

```
incidentCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(incidents$u_detailed_description))
incidentCorpus <- tm_map(incidentCorpus, tolower)
incidentCorpus <- tm_map(incidentCorpus, removePunctuation)
incidentCorpus <- tm_map(incidentCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
incidentCorpus <- tm_map(incidentCorpus, stemDocument)
incidentDTM <- DocumentTermMatrix(incidentCorpus)
```

3) Splitting data into train and test set using caTools.

```
set.seed(123)
split <- sample.split(incidentSparse$priority,SplitRatio = 0.7)
train <- subset(incidentSparse, split == TRUE)
test  <- subset(incidentSparse, split == FALSE)
train$priority <- as.character(train$priority) 
train$priority <- as.factor(train$priority
test$priority  <- as.character(testSet1$priority)
test$priority  <- as.factor(testSet1$priority)
```

4) Apply the `randomforest()` function to create my model and used `predict` function to classify my test set as well.

```
incidentRandomF <- randomForest(priority ~ ., data = train, ntree = 200, mtry = 50, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)
```

5) the overall accuracy of the model is around 90%.

```
baselineAccuracy <- sum(diag(table(predict(incidentRandomF, type="class"), train$priority)))/nrow(train)

> baselineAccuracy
[1] 0.8392498

predFinalTestSet_RF <- predict(incidentRandomF, newdata = test,  type="class")
FinalTestSetAccuracy <- sum(diag(table(test$priority,predFinalTestSet_RF)))/nrow(test)

> FinalTestSetAccuracy
[1] 0.8828125
```

As of now my classification model is ready and now I need to execute this model to predict the priority based on a given description, where the description would be provided by the user.

How to provide user input to the R script to make it functional properly?

Your help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. please check.

Comment: How do the people who want predictions want to give input? You could create a web form with rShiny, or they could send you a CSV that looks like your test set, you could distribute your trained model and they could put in values through R, there are a lot of options here.

Comment: @Josh. Thanks for your reply. I would like to create web form with ShinyR. It would be helpful if you could provide me a high level idea or any previously solved linked for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So without writing the entire page (or testing the code I wrote here), but hopefully enough to show how to get started (let me know if you have any more questions), here's how the Shiny app will basically look:

In a file called ui.R:

```
fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a text input box
  textInput("u_detailed_description", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),
  #Additional inputs for other fields here

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("prediction")))

)
```

Then in server.R:

```
function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$u_detailed_description, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ predict(incidentRandomF, newdata = input,  type="class") })

}
```

Tons of great information and documentation, including very many examples over at the [Shiny site](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)

While looking something else up, I stumbled on [this repo](https://github.com/hack-r/coursera_shiny/blob/master/server.R) that shows someone displaying predictions from a model in a Shiny app, it might help clarify how to do things like save your model and reload it and that sort of thing.

Comment: Many thanks for the snippets and the information. I shall check and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I have modified the script but getting the error **renderPrint** function.

Warning: Error in eval: object 'auto' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    91: eval
    90: eval
    89: model.frame.default
    88: model.frame
    87: predict.randomForest
    86: predict
    85: renderPrint [D:\Sourav\Analytics\Service Now/server.R#50]
    84: func
    83: eval
    82: eval
    81: withVisible
    80: evalVis
    79: utils::capture.output
    78: paste
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$prediction
     1: runApp

Comment: I believe that the columns in train set don't match with the text. May be I need to intersect the columns. Please suggest.